# How to keep a div contained within the viewport whilst maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

There exists a square div that is an arbitrary percent wide (and the same amount high) that needs to scale with the window.

It must stay within the bounds of the viewport (ie: not clipping outside) and maintain its square shape - essentially duplicating the `background-size: contain;` feature of CSS.

I need to support iOS Safari v3.2, so I can't use `vw/vh/vmin/vmax` and would *strongly* prefer a CSS-only solution.

[image]

Comment: I've had this exact problem before, but there's not really an easy answer. I wish there was, it would make my life a lot easier. Probably some javascript or jquery might be in order. If only CSS had width:50%; height:width;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it using `:after` in CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5tzk3/307/

```
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 100%; /*Sets ratio*/
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
```

Explanation:

This works by inserting no content `:after` and then giving the div a padding top of 100%, thus pushing the bottom of the div down. If you change it to, say, `padding-top: 56.25%;` it would give a 16:9 ratio. The padding does not interfere with the content of the div as it is inserted `:after` and only elements that are associated with `:after` within this element would be affected. In this case there are no elements that use `:after` as you'd always use a new div for this effect.

**Edited**

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5tzk3/309/

to stop it expanding beyond a point set a `max-width` and `max-height`

```
.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-height:350px;
    max-width:350px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. Notice that in your demo, if you change the `.wrapper` width to something like 90% and resize the window, the square starts getting cut off on the size that can't handle it.

Comment: @Vector, while this does indeed work for thin screens, notice that wide viewports will cause the large box to crop off the bottom.

Comment: @Vector no, you don't need to change the padding value if you want a different width, it should always be 100% if you want to maintain 1:1 aspect ratio

Comment: @BryceHanscomb It is not being cropped off at the bottom, it is just expanding to keep the ratio

Comment: @Vector - that is the problem. My requirement is that it *does not expand outside the container or viewport*. That's really the apex of the question.

Comment: I get what you're saying now. That is a bit of a problem, but this is a pretty solid solution for pure css. @BryceHanscomb

Comment: Umm.. I just don't understand what the position:relative and position:absolute do. Could you explain? @Vector

Comment: The max-width and max-height fixes it pretty well.

Comment: You can only use max-height and max-width values if you know the size of the container, I made a simple jquery function that dynamically "contains" the main div inside its container http://jsfiddle.net/5tzk3/311/

Comment: @eshellborn I set those position values by habit, they are not required http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5tzk3/312/

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Vector's answer in regards to cropping on the bottom:

If you have access to vw/vh you can ensure the bottom never gets cropped by setting the max-width to be 100% of the viewport height, and max-height to be 100% of the viewport-width.

e.g.
`max-width: 100vh; max-height: 100vw;`

I know the original poster indicated they did not have access to this. Just pointing this out if you find this page like I did and DO have access.